# How to remove text inside [] using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove all text including [] inside any []
for eg,  i have headers captured

```
Accept: [*/*] Accept-Language: [en-US,en;q=0.9] Cache-Control: [no-cache] Host: [localhost:8080] User-Agent: [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36] xyz: [xydd]

content.replaceAll(/ *\:.*\] */g, "");
```

but it is not working somehow

i want everything to be removed after : and ]

so result ll be like

```
Accept
Accept-Language
Cache-Control
Host
User-Agent
xyz
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Obligatory Java != JavaScript comment. Since Java isn't involved here you might want to remove that tag.

Comment: My Mistake keeping java in tag

Comment: replaceAll is not javascript String function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that matches everything but `]` instead of any character. Then, replace it with a character like `,` (or a space) and use `String.split()`. In the below example, I also use `Array.slice(0,-1)` to remove the last, empty string:

```js
var content = `Accept: [*/*] Accept-Language: [en-US,en;q=0.9] Cache-Control: [no-cache] Host: [localhost:8080] User-Agent: [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36] xyz: [xydd]`;

console.log(content.replace(/ *\:[^\]]*\] */g, ",").split(',').slice(0, -1));
```